# Refreshing a document

Tags: java, text, text-editor

I have a writing/reading .txt files program, which I will put at the bottom so I can ask my question first: Usually, if I have the file open and run the program, I need to close the .txt file and reopen it in order to see the changes the program makes. Is there a way to refresh the document in the program so that It will change before my eyes in real time? Here is the program:

```
package SingleThings;

import java.io.*;

public class TextUtil {
    public String path;
    public String[] lines;

    public TextUtil(String pathy,int length){
        path=pathy;
        makeFile();
        lines = new String[length];
        for(int i = 0;i<length;i++){
            lines[i]=getLine(i+1);
        }
    }


    public void clear(){
        try{
            FileWriter write = new FileWriter(path , false);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("There was a problem oh noesss " + e);
        }
    }

    private void makeFile(){
        try {
            File file = new File(path);
            if (file.createNewFile()){
                System.out.println("Creating file...");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Loading file...");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getLine(int line){
        BufferedReader in;
        String read = null;
        int linenum = line;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            while(linenum > 0){
                read = in.readLine();
                linenum--;
            }
            in.close();
            return read;
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("There was a problem:" + e);
            return "error";
        }
    }

    private void write(String text){
        BufferedWriter out;
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path,true));
            out.write(text);
            out.newLine();
            out.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("There was a problem:" + e);
        }
    }

    public void update(){
        clear();
        for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
            if(lines[i]!=null){
                write(lines[i]);
            }else{
                write("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit: Do you mean that you want an external editor to show your changes immediately after your program has closed its writing stream? If this is the case then your question is not Java-related but related to the specific editor you use.

Comment: It will help if you can provide a short working (modulo bugs) program, necessarily including a `main` method. Not sure if you are or need to  be running this in a separate thread.